# Select specific rows, transform and concat in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I would like to select specific rows, transform and concatenate in Python.

**Data**

```
id type stat    country
1  aa1  y       ca
2  bb2  n       ny
3  cc3  y       tx
```

**Desired**

```
Use Input("select type value:  ")

type in:  aa1, bb2

*selects appropriate rows

 id    type stat    country 
 1     aa1  y       ca  
 2     bb2  n       ny
```

Run some type of transformation - change

```
df2 = df["country"].replace({"ca": "tx"}, inplace=True)
```

Concatenate newly transformed rows subset w/ remaining dataset

```
 id    type stat    country 
 1     aa1  y       tx  
 2     bb2  n       ny
 3     cc3  y       tx
```

**Doing**

A SO member suggested this portion which works well, I am trying to piece together the remaining rows w the transformed subset

```
  out = input("select type value:  ")
  vals = [v.strip() for v in out.split(',')]
  df1 = df.query('type.isin(@vals)')
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
out = input("select type value:  ")
vals = [v.strip() for v in out.split(',')]

# Find rows where criteria match
query_mask = df["type"].isin(vals)

# Do transformation only for those rows
df[query_mask] = df.loc[query_mask].replace({"ca": "tx"})
```

If you really want remaining data to be at the end of the df:

```
out = input("select type value:  ")
vals = [v.strip() for v in out.split(',')]

# Find rows where criteria match
query_mask = df["type"].isin(vals)

# Grab rows where criteria match
query_rows = df.loc[query_mask]

# Grab leftover rows
leftover_rows = df.loc[~query_mask]

# Do transformations
query_rows.replace({"ca": "tx"}, inplace=True)

# Concatenate transformed rows and leftovers
df = pd.concat([query_rows, leftover_rows])
```

Comment: Hi I’m looking moreso to capture the remaining output in row 3 , so that I can simply concat this with df2

Comment: Simply append the remaining data (extracted with `~query_mask`): for instance appending `.append(df.loc[~query_mask, :])` to the last line of code.

Comment: Updated my answer for concatenation approach

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `pandasql` + `update`

```
import pandasql as ps

type = 'aa1','bb1'
q1 = """SELECT * FROM df where type in ('%s','%s') """ %(type)
df.update(ps.sqldf(q1, locals()).replace({"ca": "tx"}))
df
Out[257]: 
    id type stat country
0  1.0  aa1    y      tx
1  2.0  bb2    n      ny
2  3.0  cc3    y      tx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mask` and `combine_first`:

```
df = df.mask(~df['id'].isin(vals)).replace({'country': {'ca': 'tx'}}) \
       .combine_first(df)
print(df)

# Output
    id type stat country
1  aa1         y      tx
2  bb2         n      ny
3  cc3         y      tx
```

Comment: Thank you @corralien - really wondering how to capture that first dataset - row3- how would I capture that in a variable (the remaining dataset after the subset query) - oh perhaps w combine_first

Comment: `mask` replace values of rows you don't want by nan then you can apply your transformation on other rows you selected then `combine_first` restore masked values.